# Unable to run Android Studio Emulator - "(VT-x) is not turned one" when installing HAXm

Tags: android, emulation, virtualization, haxm

I've seen many posts similar to my problem, and even though I tried to do the same steps, it still didn't work.

Intel Core i7 - 2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz  Windows 10

I need to create an emulator for Android Studio in order to test my apps, but it doesnt work, it says that I need Intel HAXM.
Then I try to install and says (VT-x) is not enable (like in the picture below)

[Error while installing HAXM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dUHp.png))

I've already tried:

(1) **Check the BIOS** (there is no option in my BIOS about VT-x virtualization, but I've check with the application "coreinfo" that says its actually working on my system.

(2) **Disable Hyper-V on Windows** (also, I couldn't find this option on "Windows Features" on Windows 10, but I've disabled everything that says Hyper-V in Windows "Services"

(3) **I've checked about AVAST**.

(4) **I've updated my Windows**

Thank you guys!!

I just don't get the fact that Windows doesnt show the Hyper-V option, and the BIOS doesnt give VT-x option also, but the Haxm_check says:
"VT support -- yes
 NX support -- yes"

Comment: Hey guys, if someone has the same problem, I was able to instal HAXm by executing the file silent_install on cmd. I just don't know exactly what happens, but it did work.
By the way, im using Windows 10 PRO now, i don't know if this change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what OS you're using. Have you tried downloading separate installer rather than install thru Android studio
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
also run the bcedit commands to make sure the CPU is enabled, not just capable
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn

Comment: Thank you codecats. I'm actually using Windows 10, I've tried download a separate installer as you suggested, and ran the bcedit commands, which shows "operation" is concluded.  But the instalation still didn't work .. I'll do some more checks here, and I'll post here more results soon.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your list shows hypervisor enabled. You should go into control panel>Programs>turn WINDOWS features on/off on the left side. Then whether it's on or off you should still see the HyperV checkbox. Make sure nothing is checked. If it's really off, you should be able to search for HyperV Manager and not find it.

Comment: I've just figured out that HyperV is not available for Windows 10 Home edition, that's why mine doesnt show the options.. I also can't find it when searching